# Cognito: How to correctly implement enhanced simplified authentication flow

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get the enhanced simplified authentication flow described on [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html)

[image]

Problem is I can't figure out how to correctly use the SDK ...

```
  AWS.config.region = "ap-northeast-2"
  const cognitoParams = {
    IdentityPoolId: "ap-northeast-2:...",
    Logins: {
      "accounts.google.com": googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
    }
  }
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(cognitoParams)

  const identity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity()
  identity.getId(cognitoParams, function (err, identityId) {
    console.log(identityId)

    const identityParams = Object.assign({}, cognitoParams, {
      IdentityId: identityId
    })

    identity.getCredentialsForIdentity(identityParams, function (err, data) {
      console.log(data)
    })
  })
```

The 2 `console.log` gives `null`

```
AWS.config.region = "ap-northeast-2"
const cognitoParams = {
  IdentityPoolId: "ap-northeast-2:31cc246c-bd2e-46ee-91da-2b8eefcf0745",
  Logins: {
    "accounts.google.com": googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
  }
}
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(cognitoParams)

AWS.config.credentials.getId(function (err, identityId) {
  console.log(identityId)

  const identityParams = Object.assign({}, cognitoParams, {
    IdentityId: identityId
  })

  AWS.config.credentials.getCredentialsForIdentity(identityParams, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

The above gives me the identity but fails with `Cannot read property 'getCredentialsForIdentity' of undefined`.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the below works ... I should be calling functions from an instance of `CognitoIdentity` rather than `CognitoIdentityCredentials` ... but it isn't clear in the documentations.

In fact it uses `CognitoIdentityCredentials` and reason for that? When do I use either?

```
  AWS.config.region = "ap-northeast-2"
  const cognitoParams = {
    IdentityPoolId: "ap-northeast-2:31cc246c-bd2e-46ee-91da-2b8eefcf0745",
    Logins: {
      "accounts.google.com": googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
    }
  }
  // AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(cognitoParams)

  const identity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity()
  identity.getId(cognitoParams, function (err, identityData) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err)
    }

    const identityParams = {
      IdentityId: identityData.IdentityId,
      Logins: cognitoParams.Logins
    }

    identity.getCredentialsForIdentity(identityParams, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err)
      }
      console.log(data)
    })
```